# bash - passing variable to find command -exec

Tags: bash, sed

I have a script that is like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

OLD_PATH_BASE=./components/
NEW_PATH_BASE=../../../react_components/

find . -regextype sed -regex "\./rockstart_\w\+_app/static/js/\w\+\.js" -exec sed -i "s@^\(import \w\+ from '\)$OLD_PATH_BASE\(\w\+/\w\+\.jsx';\)@\1$NEW_PATH_BASE\2@" {} \;
```

This works as I expect, but when I do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

OLD_PATH_BASE=./components/
NEW_PATH_BASE=../../../react_components/

SED_COMMAND='sed -i "s@^\(import \w\+ from '"'\)$OLD_PATH_BASE\(\w\+/\w\+\.jsx';\)@\1$NEW_PATH_BASE\2@"'"'
find . -regextype sed -regex "\./rockstart_\w\+_app/static/js/\w\+\.js" -exec $SED_COMMAND {} \;
```

It doesn't work and gives me the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `"'
```

even though when i `echo $SED_COMMAND`, it shows the right command. What's wrong

Comment: Read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050, then read it again.

Comment: BTW, see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, which goes into naming conventions for environment variables (with which shell variables share a namespace). Short form: All-caps names are used by the shell and operating system; it's names with at least one lower-case character that are reserved for application use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array will work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

old_path_base=./components/
new_path_base=../../../react_components/

# this is totally unnecessary, but IMHO makes your code easier to read
# ...huge long lines being unweildy by nature, after all.
sed_pieces=(
   's'
   "^\(import \w\+ from '\)${old_path_base}\(\w\+/\w\+\.jsx';\)"
   "\1${new_path_base}\2"
   '' # flags; empty set
)

# ...using an array for sed_command is the important part:
IFS='@' # this makes "${array[*]}" combine pieces with @s
sed_command=( sed -i "${sed_pieces[*]}" )

find . -regextype sed \
  -regex "\./rockstart_\w\+_app/static/js/\w\+\.js" \
  -exec "${sed_command[@]}" {} +
```

---

Explanation:

- Expanding a string unquoted (as in your failed attempt) doesn't run the expansion result through the full parser, but instead through string-splitting and glob-expansion stages only; thus, quotes aren't parsed and consumed. This is a feature, not a bug -- if every expansion ran the full parser, writing secure code in shell would be effectively impossible. Read [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for a full explanation of the behavior at hand and best-practice workarounds.

  To provide a shorter, simpler example:

  ```
  a_command='touch "hello world"'
  $a_command
  ```

  ...will actually create *two* files: one named `"hello`, and one named `world"`; this is because the only processing steps `$a_command` runs through are string-splitting (splitting into words based on spaces) and glob expansion (evaluating each item created by that split process to see if it's a glob expression, and replacing it with a list of matching files if so).
- `-exec ... {} +` passes multiple input filenames to each invocation of the `exec`'d command; it is thus an efficiency improvement where allowed (which is certainly the case here, as any `sed` which supports the `-i` extension will also support multiple input files).

Answer (score 2):

I guess the easiest way would be to use a function here.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash=
#Below function wraps the whole of sed processing part
sed_fun()
{
OLD_PATH_BASE=./components/
NEW_PATH_BASE=../../../react_components/
sed -i "s@^\(import \w\+ from '\)$OLD_PATH_BASE\(\w\+/\w\+\.jsx';\)@\1$NEW_PATH_BASE\2@" "$@"
}

export -f sed_fun

find . -regextype sed -regex "\./rockstart_\w\+_app/static/js/\w\+\.js" -exec bash -c 'sed_fun "$0"' {} \;
```

Or use an array :

```
sed_command=(sed -i "s@^\(import \w\+ from '\)$OLD_PATH_BASE\(\w\+/\w\+\.jsx';\)@\1$NEW_PATH_BASE\2@")
find . -regextype sed -regex "\./rockstart_\w\+_app/static/js/\w\+\.js"  -exec bash -c 'sed_fun  "$@"' _ {} \+
```

**Note:** As [@Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) mentioned in his comment, it is not a good practice using fully upper-case variables for the application as such variables are usually reserved for the system.

**Reference**

1. `find` [[ Complex Actions ]](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Complex_actions) for a nice description on `-exec bash -c 'sed_fun "$0"' {} \;`
2. Find [[ manpage ]](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)

Comment: You aren't quoting the expansion of your array.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Thank-you. I did that & also changed the variable to name to lowercase as you've mentioned in the comment.

Comment: Indeed. The other change I might suggest is updating the function to take more than one argument -- if you fill in a placeholder for `$0`, then you could pass `"$@"` through and use `-exec {} +`; that's a larger performance enhancement here when you're running not just `sed` but a new instance of `bash` for each file.

Comment: [...huh. I don't think this deserves a downvote -- the exported-function approach is a perfectly good way to wrap arbitrary shell code to be run from a bash instance exec'd by a subprocess, and it's worth showcasing].

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Updated based on comment#3. Thanks for that suggestion. It's the first time I'm using `find -exec command {} +`. So, was reading the manual on that

Comment: I was just missing "export myVariable" and -exec sh -c was able to see it. No sed needed.